# Finer resolution pixels inside a coarser resolution pixel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I have a big/coarser raster pixel of 6 km and a finer resolution raster of 500 m. Both the rasters have the same coordinates and belong to the same area. Now, I want to find which 144 smaller pixels lie inside a particular bigger/coarser pixel, so what tool/method in ArcGIS can I use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends entirely what you mean by "I want to find which...".

Normally one would be summarizing the smaller pixels by the larger, you would use the zonal statistics tool for that operation to generate min/max/mean type statistics.

If by "I want to find which..." you mean you want the coordinates of those smaller cells then personally I would move the problem out into vector data. Convert you smaller pixels to points, add your coordinate information to the points using the add XY coordinates tool. Convert your larger pixels to polygons then do a select by location to identify the points in question. This logic could be wrapped up into a simple model for automation.